# True single phase clock based flip flop

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, flipflop

Can anyone explain in detail how the true single phase clock below works? 
  I need to understand it well so I can design it with CMOS technology and know how to size W/L for each MOS transistor.

Link: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)), at section Edge-triggered dynamic D storage element.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you simulate it in LTSpice (free)?

Comment: I already created that D flip flop and made shift register but the output signal of shift register overlap. So I need to understand how that D flip flop works first. I don't understand how it work just by simulation. If I have basic about this, then simulation may be helpful. However, this type of flip flop is completely new to me, so it doesn't not help.

Comment: the detailed explanation is given here. http://www.ece.ncsu.edu/asic/ece733/2012/docs/FlipFlops.pdf Pages 28-30 Take careful notes of the issues on p31.

Comment: @anhnha It is not zero hold time so it needs some logic between stages to give delay between the flops. An ordinary shift register will connect Q to D with only a small delay from the output inverter.

Comment: Note the short if \$\bar{R}\$ is asserted while \$\bar{Q}\$ is driven low by the previous stage.

Comment: Note this question is already well documented on the web, so isn't this redundant?  What additional parameters do you need defined to make this "truely" a good question for a True edge triggered CMOS FF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting design, but it looks very sensitive to the process used. Fundamentally, it's a dynamic RAM cell, so the state is stored as charge on the node labeled !Q, using the gate capacitances of M7 and M12. The unusual part is that it also briefly stores charge in two other locations: the gate of M5, and the gates of M3 and M10.

Let's call each column of transistors in the diagram a stage, so for example stage 1 consists of M1, M4, and M8.

Suppose the clock input is 0 and the data input is also 0. In this case, the output of stage 1 is 1, the output of stage 2 is 1, and the output of stage 3 is high-impedance, meaning that its output is not connected to either power rail. As a result, the charge at !Q does not change. Now suppose the clock signal goes high. This causes the output of stage 1 to go high-impedance, so it remains at 1 because of the charge stored on the gate of M5. Stage 2 now outputs 0, so stage 3 outputs 1, which causes charge to be stored at !Q if it was not already. The data value has been latched.

Suppose instead that the clock input is 0 and the data input is 1. In this case, the output of stage 1 is 0, the output of stage 2 is 1, and the output of stage 3 is high-impedance. As a result, the charge at !Q does not change. Now suppose the clock signal goes high.  Stage 1 still outputs 0, so the output of stage 2 is high-impedance, which means it remains at 1 because of the charge stored on the gates of M3 and M10. Stage 3 now outputs 0, which removes any charge stored at !Q.

Stage 4 is the reset: when !R is brought low, M11 turns on, ensuring that !Q is charged. Stage 5 is an inverter, so that Q will be 1 when !Q is 0 and vice versa. It also acts as a buffer, allowing current to be draw from Q without affecting the charge at !Q.

The clever aspect of this design, and the reason it's so complicated, is that it is edge-triggered: a change to D while the clock is high does not affect the output: suppose D is 0 while clock is 1, and then D goes to 1. This will cause the output of stage 1 to go to 0, which will cause stage 2 to go high-impedance, so its output of 0 will be preserved by capacitance and the output of stage 3 will not change. Similarly, if D is 1 while clock is 1, and then D goes to 0, stage 1 will go high-impedance, preserving its output of 0, so subsequent stages will not change.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I think their a problem here. In your analysis, the data doesn't change while the clock is high. What happen if the input D change from 0 to 1 while clock is high? The output Q also changes because S1 changes.

Comment: @anhnha It actually does only trigger on an edge: I've edited my answer with some details of how it works. Basically, a change to D while the clock is high makes some nodes go high-impedance, but they keep their state due to the gate capacitance.

Comment: Thanks. I see it now. For the case D goes from 0 to 1 while clock is high, the output of the first stage will change but the output of second stage doesn't change. That will keep the output Q unchanged.

Comment: @anhnha Exactly. Anything else that's unclear about its operation? By the way, if you're actually implementing this flip-flop in a design, make sure that the clock will be toggled often enough that the stored charge does not leak away (how long that takes is a question for the silicon fab).

Answer (score 2):

To discuss, I added 3 signal labels (in blue) to your diagram:

[image]
To understand this circuit, it helps to think of it as in stages.

**Stage 5** is a simple inverter.

**Stage 4** is pull-up controlled by the \$\bar{R}\$ signal that when asserted pulls high S3, forcing Q to 1. The only issue I see here is that there is a possibility of shorting Vdd to Gnd via M11-M6-M3. Let's ignore that for now.

**Stage 1** can be thought of as:
[image]

When there is Z (high impedance), it is assumed that the value is the same as the last actively driven, and maintained by the parasitic capacitances (mostly that of the MOSFET gate(s) of the following stage).

Note that RST has precedence. This effectively behaves like an S-R latch with its S input inverted.

**Stage 2** and **stage 3** are topologically identical, and very similar to stage 1 (except that \$\overline{SET}\$ has precedence). They can be thought of as follows:

[image]

One interesting feature is that if one of the inputs is deasserted, then the output can either stay where it is, or flip once in the direction associated with the other input if it gets asserted.

The connections are as follows:

```
Stage !SET  RST
  1    Clk  D
  2    Clk  S1
  3    S2   Clk
```

The trick to how it works boils down to the first two stages (S1 and S2) having Clk as their \$\overline{SET}\$.

We start off with Clk as 0. S1 basically inverts D, and S2 is fixed to 1.

On the rising edge of Clk, their \$\overline{SET}\$ becomes deasserted, which means that their outputs can only flip to 0 (or remain at 1). Because they are in series, S1 determines S2's flip to 0 (when S1 is 1). But if S1 was 1 to begin with, then S2 changed to 0 at the flank (which is the opposite of S1, and now S2 can't go back to 1), and if S1 was 0 to begin with, then S1 cannot change anyway (even if D changes), and S2 remains with its original value of 1 (which is also the opposite of S1).

So together they trap D in S2 at the positive edge of the clock.

While Clk remains at 1, S3 is effectively \$\overline{S2}\$. And since S2 does not change, neither does S3. By the way, since S2 was fixed to 1 right before the flank, S3 may glitch to 0 momentarily, right before getting its proper value.

When Clk drops to 0, S2 is forced to 1 (because \$\overline{SET}\$ has precedence), therefore S3 has neither \$\overline{SET}\$ or RST asserted, and it maintains its value. In the meantime, S1 becomes \$\overline{D}\$, getting ready for the next rising edge of Clk.

So basically S2 changes to S1's prepped D value at rising edge of Clk and stays there, this propagates to S3 shortly after (and becomes Q after the stage 5 inverter), and when Clk drops to 0, S3 is maintained (hence Q), while S1 queues up the next D, and S2 is fixed to 1.

At the end of the day, it behaves like a normal FF from the outside, except that since internal signals are maintained by capacitance, leakage will eventually corrupt the values if they are not refreshed often by cycling the clock and constantly repeating this sequence of events.

Comment: Thanks for great answer. I almost got it just one problem relating to output changes while clock is high and data changes from 0 to 1. For edge triggered flip flop the output should not change while data changes right after rising clock.

Comment: @anhnha It doesn't. At the edge, S2 is resolved and D does not affect it anymore. Therefore S3 and Q are also stable. You can verify that by simulation.